# No Saga in QGIS 2.12

Tags: qgis, installation, saga, windows-7

After installed QGIS 2.12 I don't have SAGA in Processing Toolbox anymore and I need it bad. Am I blind, can't find it or something went wrong? Any suggestions please?
My OS is Win 7 64 bit.

Comment: OsGeo or Standallone install?

Comment: Standallone install.

Comment: main thing if you install qgis via OSGEO4w in advanced mode (that you did not do it) you have to choose the other packages you want. Obviously this is not your case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed this too, under Windows. I installed SAGA on it's own, then under Processing > Options > Providers > SAGA, I gave QGIS the path to the install folder, and presto. :)

You can always use SAGA on it's own, by the way, including through the command line, via `saga_cmd`.

(Also, make sure you switched to "Advanced Interface" in your QGIS Processing window.)