# Set path to SAGA from QGIS on OSX

Tags: qgis, saga, mac

After a crash and subsequent reinstall I cannot access SAGA GIS in the processing toolbox, and it appears that QGIS can't find it as there is no setting for the path.

**How can I set the path from QGIS to SAGA? There is no option in the Providers menu.**

The question have been up before, and the solution that worked in most cases have been to enable and/or set the right path in processing toolbox - options - providers (see eg. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87065/enabling-saga-in-qgis), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171571/no-saga-in-qgis-2-12) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86830/how-to-make-grass-and-saga-tools-capable-to-use-in-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1)). I tried to reinstall QGIS, SAGA and all dependencies, but no success.

According to the accepted answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216614/how-to-change-saga-path-in-qgis-2-18-standalone), the problem was solved in QGIS 2.18.2 on Windows, but maybe not for Mac? Am I missing something?

I can tic 'Activate' in options -> provider, but there is no option to set the path (GRASS and GDAL have the option and works fine):

[image]

It is also confirmed in the advanced options settings:

[image]

SAGA is installed and appears to work:

[image]

and available here:

```
$ which saga_cmd
/opt/local/bin/saga_cmd
```

I'm using latest Kyngkaos. QGIS 2.18.13:

[image]

On OS X 10.11.6:

[image]

Comment: Your main problem is your SAGA version (5.0.0) is not supported. As of (I think) QGIS 2.18, only the SAGA LTR ( currently 2.3.2) is supported. I am assuming this is why you can no longer set or change the path to the SAGA folder (since external SAGA installations are not supported). 2.3.2 is also the version shipped with the QGIS standalone installer. I am not a Mac user so I'm afraid I can't give you much help with your installation process but you need to roll back your SAGA version to the LTR.

Comment: @BenW I think your comment is worth a full answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your main problem is that the SAGA version you have installed (5.0.0) as shown in your screen shot, is not supported. As of (I think) QGIS 2.18, only the SAGA Long Term Release (currently 2.3.2) is supported. I am assuming this is why it is no longer possible to set or change the path to the SAGA folder (since external SAGA installations are not supported). 2.3.2 is also the version shipped with the QGIS standalone installer. I am not a Mac user so I'm afraid I can't give you much help with your installation process but you need to roll back your SAGA version to the LTR.

Comment: I have the same problem. SAGA was there in QGIS until just recetly. But unlike @Tbb  I have SAGA version is 2.2.2 installed on the system so that version problem you're addressing shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: I updated SAGA in an attempt to solve the problem, so there is something else going on. I also experienced the same on another Ubuntu computer with SAGA LTR. When I get back to office I'll update the question and/or hopefully solve the problem.

Comment: @oskarlin, 2.2.2 is an older version so I think it will give you compatability issues as well. 2.3.2 is the currently supported LTR. Which OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running macOS and I haven’t installed saga recently. It worked until the other day... perhaps when I installed the latest QGIS from kyngchaos.