# SAGA disappears from QGIS 2.18.14

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-processing, saga, mac

I upgraded QGIS from 2.18.0 to 2.18.14 but I losted Saga in processing tools.

First I tried to disable/reactivate it in processing > options > providers but nothing.

I searched some solution on web and I saw that I can't change Saga folder in providers.

[image]

So I find a way to change it in QGIS advanced options > processing > configuration menu. I tried some folders but nothing worked...

[image]

In others gis stackexchange posts people said to use Osgeo4W Saga installation but i'm on mac OS not on Windows...

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258826/set-path-to-saga-from-qgis-on-osx

Comment: @LennertDeFeyter : it's a good way that I'm exploring. I install LTS saga gis version 2.3.2 with HomeBrew `brew install saga-gis`. But now i'm searching which folder I have to set up in Qgis advanced option...

Comment: I tried `/usr/local/Cellar/saga-gis-lts/2.3.2`, `/usr/local/Cellar/saga-gis-lts/2.3.2/lib`, `/usr/local/Cellar/saga-gis-lts/2.3.2/bin`. I don't know what he needs to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing **SagaAlgorithmProvider.py** will add SAGA to the processing menu, but may not work, depending on your setup.

A lot of the SAGA command line options changed between 2.2 and 2.3, so some of the algorithms won't work. Processing thinks it's calling 2.3, and sets the command line options accordingly. SAGA 2.2 then complains about unknown parameters.

> > I'm using a Mac, with the KyngChaos build of QGIS (2.18.13, Nov 2017)

I got SAGA 2.3 to work by installing the SAGA LTS using homebrew...

```
brew install saga-gis-lts
```

Calling

```
saga_cmd --version
```

shows it's 2.3.2

Using

```
which saga_cmd
```

shows saga_cmd lives in **/usr/local/bin**

When processing starts up, it looks in the QGIS install folder for SAGA. The KyngChaos build includes saga 2.2, so Processing will choose that, rather than 2.3.2.

To get around that, I edited the **SagaUtils.py**, commenting out and replacing the line 'testfolder='

```
def findSagaFolder():
    folder = None
    if isMac():
        #testfolder = os.path.join(QgsApplication.prefixPath(), 'bin')
        testfolder = '/usr/local/bin'
        . . .
```

Restarted QGIS, and SAGA 2.3 is available :-)

Comment: Where I find SagaUtils.py ?

Comment: it should be the same directory as the SagaAlgorithmProvider.py (for me, the same directory as in your answer)

Comment: It works ! But i have to reset **SagaAlgorithmProvider.py** with `if not version.startswith('2.3.')` line 76.

Answer (score 3):

Qgis user list, in particular Carlos Cerdan helped me to fix this issue. So I share solution:

1. Go to `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga`
2. Open **SagaAlgorithmProvider.py** in your favorite text editor
3. go to line **76** and change: `if not version.startswith('2.3.'):` to e.g.: `if not version.startswith('2.2.'):`

It works for me, I hope it can help !

**EDIT**:
This way only permit to use Saga 2.2.* which is provided with Qgis 2.18.*